# using Ionic all of a sudden all my icons and images not working on all projects

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3, ionic4

I have three projects which had images and icons now none work. I am not quite sure what happened but my files are referenced in HTML and in TS files none work.

The files are located under src/assetts as images and they are referenced as so:

```
<img alt="logo" height="60" src="../../assets/icon/logotxt3.png">
```

and I have tried as so:

```
<img alt="logo" height="60" src="assets/icon/logotxt3.png">
<img alt="logo" height="60" src="/assets/icon/logotxt3.png">
```

I don't know what is going on my ionic version is 6.16.2 I am using Angular.

Update:

I created a new project and moved my files app folder content and now that one works with new project files. What happened with all other ones? I am kinda at lost of what happened not to just one but all now.

Comment: seems like an ionic bug. report this on their github repo.